# Image orientation issue in android react native

Tags: react-native, photo-gallery, camera-roll

i'm using `CameraRoll.getPhotos` for get photos from gallery.

```
import {
  CameraRoll,
} from 'react-native';

CameraRoll.getPhotos(fetchParams).then((data) => {
});
```

I have a problem with the orientation of the images on some android phones. I have been able to detect what happens in most SAMSUNGs.

It has an orientation depending on the way you take the picture.

`portrait with home button in bottom position`: **90º**
`landscape with home button left position`: **180º**
`portrait with home button in top position`: **270º**
`landscape with home button right position`: **0º**

Related with [this issue](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1845)

Base on [CameraRoll Documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/cameraroll.html) the orientation value is not returned by `getPhotos`.

**I'm try with:**

- `transform: [{ rotateX: '0deg' }, { rotateY: '0deg' }]` or `rotate: '0deg'`
- Using `react-native-media-meta` for get metadata info [(not works)](https://github.com/mybigday/react-native-media-meta/issues/17)
- Use another image component instead native `Image`

***but notting works. :(***

The problem is that the images appear rotated in my application, but in the native gallery ignores the degree of rotation they have and shows them correctly with **0º**.

**Example**:

[image]

In this case the image appear with **90º** and it's showed perfectly by native gallery but bad in my app.

**- Is there any way to detect the current rotation of the image?**
**- Can the `<Image>` component be forced in some way to place the orientation at 0º?**

---

***UPDATE:***

i found a library [this module](https://github.com/francisco-sanchez-molina/react-native-exif) and its possible get the orientation of image and with that can fix this problem. But this process is very delayed and affect considerably the perfomance.